# How to concatenate and convert hex to base 64 in Python?

Tags: python, hex, base64, decimal

I'm trying to convert hex values into base 64.

I have a script that does some calculations to each value.
I then want to convert the final values to base 64.

```
import base64
for i, v in enumerate([0x31, 0x37, 0x32, 0x2e]):
    z=i+v #adds positional index to hex value
    q=z+0x27 #adds constant 
    x=q^i # XORs with positional index
print (x)
```

gives:

> 88
>   94
>   89
>   91

I'm trying to convert these values into base 64.
If I manually put them in this form: `585e595b`, this code is working:

```
>>> "585e595b".decode('hex').encode('base64')
'WF5ZWw==\n'
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "hex values" - hexadecimal is just one of many representations for a value. You chose to write your four values in hex on line 2, but after that they're just values (integers to be exact). So, given that, what exactly is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it:

```
data = [0x31, 0x37, 0x32, 0x2e]
encoded = base64.b64encode(''.join(hex(x)[2:] for x in data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Working it into your existing code... convert to hex, then chop off the `0x` and accumulate in a variable. When you're done, do as you've suggested. I get `WF5ZWw==` for output.

```
import base64
string = ''
for i, v in enumerate([0x31, 0x37, 0x32, 0x2e]):
    z=i+v #adds positional index to hex value
    q=z+0x27 #adds constant 
    x=q^i # XORs with positional index
    string += hex(x)[2:]
print string.decode('hex').encode('base64')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to do, but I get the feeling you're looking for [`chr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) to turn an ordinal integer to its respective ASCII character:

```
values = []

for i, v in enumerate([0x31, 0x37, 0x32, 0x2e]):
    z=i+v #adds positional index to hex value
    q=z+0x27 #adds constant
    x=q^i # XORs with positional index
    values.append(x)

print "585e595b".decode('hex') .encode('base64')

s = ''.join([chr(i) for i in values])
print s.encode('base64')
```

Output:

```
WF5ZWw==

WF5ZWw==
```

Comment: For python-3 use: 

`import codecs, base64;  base64.b64encode(codecs.decode(b"585e595b"))`.

Answer (score 0):

wow, you answered yourself!

You can do the encoding or decoding transformations from a string:

```
print str(x).encode('base64')    # should be something like this
```

I also believe that you have an issue with your algorithm because the numbers doesn't stack into the x variable.
Only last number is printing.